# Different order of the calls to ConfigureServices between .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1 in WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.1

During migration from .NET Core 2 to 3, I've noticed a breaking change in the `WebApplicationFactory`. Repro: https://github.com/lukasz-pyrzyk/orderofconfigureservices

In my base library for integration test, I've used `WebApplicationFactory` to setup a server and configure services. For example, imagine the following services

```cs
public interface IHelloService
{
    string Say();
}

public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    public string Say() => "Hello from original service";
}

public class CustomHelloService : IHelloService
{
    public string Say() => "Hello from custom service";
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHelloService, HelloService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    }
}
```

Base class for integration tests and the fixture looks as follow

```cs
public class TestFixture : IntegrationTests<Startup>
{
    [Fact]
    public void SayHallo()
    {
        var service = Services.GetService<IHelloService>();
        Assert.Equal("Hello from custom service", service.Say());
    }

    protected override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHelloService, CustomHelloService>();
    }
}


public abstract class IntegrationTests<TStartup> : IDisposable where TStartup : class
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> _factory;

    protected IntegrationTests() : this(typeof(TStartup).Assembly.GetName().Name)
    {
    }

    protected IntegrationTests(string projectRelativePath)
    {
        _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>().WithWebHostBuilder(b =>
        {
            b
                .UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot(Path.Combine("src", projectRelativePath))
                .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
        });

        _factory.CreateClient();
        Services = _factory.Services;
    }
    
    protected IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _factory.Dispose();
    }
}
```

On .NET Core 2.1 and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing 2.1.3` method, `TestFixture.ConfigureServices()` is called **before** `Startup.ConfigureServices` and the **test passes**.

On .NET Core 3.1 and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing 3.1.1` method, `TestFixture.ConfigureServices()` is called **after** `Startup.ConfigureServices` and the **test fails**.

Do you know if this change was intentional? With .NET Core 2.1, ConfigureServices from test was called first and `TryAddSingleton` was registering my mock service. Later on, `Startup.ConfigureServices` skipped registration, because service was already added.

With .NET Core 3.1 I'm forced to call `AddSingleton` which replaces the service. Is it a bug or a wanted change? Can I overcome it somehow?